# Jquery, Error happens uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one issue and have no idea how to fix it. I am new to Jquery. Could someone provide any help? I used some links to access Jquery contextMenu, but then I found the error by looking at the content from developer tool. Is this a error from the contextmenu?

I took a look at the page there is no error and works ok.

I added some link to access context menu, the error came out when start to run index.html by using vscode with live server.

this is what I added in the index.html, before I added the code, there is no error

```
  <script src="libs/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/jQuery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/ol.js"></script>
    
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.ui.position.js"></script> 
       <script src="/src/js/contextFile.js"></script>
<script>

......

  new contextFile();
</script>
```

Error information:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of null
        at Re (jQuery.min.js:2)
        at We (jQuery.min.js:2)
        at Function.css (jQuery.min.js:2)
        at jQuery.min.js:2
        at $ (jQuery.min.js:2)
        at S.fn.init.css (jQuery.min.js:2)
        at jquery.contextMenu.min.js? [sm]:263
        at S.fn.init.show (jquery.contextMenu.min.js? [sm]:992)
        at HTMLHtmlElement.contextmenu (jquery.contextMenu.min.js? [sm]:338)
        at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jQuery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: It will be helpfully, to know witch jQuery version you are using.

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your suggestion.The version of jQuery is v3.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved ,because I used selector("html").In this contextMenu,the selector should be div or body instead of html.Some function will be called from the div or body.

$.contextMenu(
selector: 'body',
callback=(key, options)=> {
var msg = "clicked: " + key;
window.console && console.log(msg) || alert(msg);
},
items: {......